# Microsoft SQL Server Time and Date query

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a large data set that records all jobs that have run for an ETL tool. There are about 1500 jobs that run per day and a lot of them can run for less than 10 seconds.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC4eC.png)

What I am trying to do is get some statistics for run times of these run times.

Ideally I wanted a run time for all jobs per day and was running this query:

```
SELECT 
    RUNDATE = CAST(runstart AS date), 
    TOTALRUNTIME = CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', CAST(RUNTIME AS time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00') AS Time) 
FROM 
    "CADIS"."vwSolutionHistory" 
GROUP BY 
    CAST(runstart AS date)
```

However this returned some weird results.

For example one day showed a total run time of 23:56:27.4833333, and on average we only have jobs running about 11 - 12 hours a day so a total run time of 23 hours didn't make sense. So if anyone has ideas on how to make that work that would be fantastic

Anyway I moved on and grouped the results by name as well so am getting a sum of the total time per job per day

```
SELECT 
    RUNDATE = CAST(runstart AS date), 
    NAME, 
    TOTALRUNTIME = CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', RUNTIME)), '00:00:00.000'), 108) 
FROM 
    "CADIS"."vwSolutionHistory" 
WHERE
    TIMESINCELASTENTRY IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    name, CAST(runstart AS date) 
ORDER BY
    2, 1
```

What I would like to do in addition to this is to (1) get the total time of each time per day (per above query) (2) get the maximum time a job took per day (3) Get the median time a job took per day (4) Get the minimum time a job took per day

However, I'm not sure what how to get all of those 4 things in one query.

Comment: Given the runstart and runend times for a lot jobs overlap... have you considered that perhaps it's running jobs in parallel?

Comment: Sample input and expected results would help